# NYT article search API not returning results for certain queries

Tags: api

I have a set of queries and I am trying to get web_urls using the NYT article search API. But I am seeing that it works for q2 below but not for q1.

q1: Seattle+Jacob Vigdor+the University of Washington

q2: Seattle+Jacob Vigdor+University of Washington

If you paste the url below with your API key in the web browser, you get an empty result.

**Search request for q1**

api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=Seattle+Jacob%20Vigdor+the%20University%20of%20Washington&begin_date=20170626&api-key=XXXX

**Empty results for q1**

{"response":{"meta":{"hits":0,"time":27,"offset":0},"docs":[]},"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2013 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved."}

Instead if you paste the following in your web browser (without the article 'the' in the query) you get non-empty results

**Search request for q2**

api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=Seattle+Jacob%20Vigdor+University%20of%20Washington&begin_date=20170626&api-key=XXXX

**Non-empty results for q2**

{"response":{"meta":{"hits":1,"time":22,"offset":0},"docs":[{"web_url":"https://www.nytimes.com/aponline/2017/06/26/us/ap-us-seattle-minimum-wage.html","snippet":"Seattle's $15-an-hour minimum wage law has cost the city jobs, according to a study released Monday that contradicted another new study published last week....","lead_paragraph":"Seattle's $15-an-hour minimum wage law has cost the city jobs, according to a study released Monday that contradicted another new study published last week.","abstract":null,"print_page":null,"blog":[],"source":"AP","multimedia":[],"headline":{"main":"New Study of Seattle's $15 Minimum Wage Says It Costs Jobs","print_headline":"New Study of Seattle's $15 Minimum Wage Says It Costs Jobs"},"keywords":[],"pub_date":"2017-06-26T15:16:28+0000","document_type":"article","news_desk":"None","section_name":"U.S.","subsection_name":null,"byline":{"person":[],"original":"By THE ASSOCIATED PRESS","organization":"THE ASSOCIATED PRESS"},"type_of_material":"News","_id":"5951255195d0e02550996fb3","word_count":643,"slideshow_credits":null}]},"status":"OK","copyright":"Copyright (c) 2013 The New York Times Company.  All Rights Reserved."}

Interestingly, both queries work fine on the api test page
http://developer.nytimes.com/article_search_v2.json#/Console/

Also, if you look at the article below returned by q2, you see that the query term in q1, 'the University of Washington' does occur in it and it should have returned this article.
https://www.nytimes.com//aponline//2017//06//26//us//ap-us-seattle-minimum-wage.html

I am confused about this behaviour of the API. Any ideas what's going on? Am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug. Not sure if the failin... er, the NYT's api support docs redirected you here. If so, you might get some clarification. if not, you probably need to open a fake... um, a support case with their API team.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I just want to know what other things it does not work for so that I can get web_urls for my search queries reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers. Below I am pasting the answer I received from NYT developers.

NYT's Article Search API uses Elasticsearch. There are lots of docs online about the query syntax of Elasticsearch (it is based on Lucene).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

If you want articles that contain "Seattle", "Jacob Vigdor" and "University of Washington", do

"Seattle" AND "Jacob Vigdor" AND "University of Washington"

or

+"Seattle" +"Jacob Vigdor" +"University of Washington"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change encoding of spaces (`%20`) to + (`%2B`):

In your example,

```
q=Seattle+Jacob%20Vigdor+the%20University%20of%20Washington
```

When I submit from the page on the site, it uses %2B:

```
q=Seattle%2BJacob+Vigdor%2Bthe+University+of+Washington
```

How are you URL encoding? One way to fix it would be to replace your spaces with `+` before URL encoding.

Also, you may need to replace `%20` with `+`. There are various schemes for URL encoding, so the best way would depend on how you are doing it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I see. When I replace %20 by %2B it seems to be working. But then there are two questions:

Comment: Great! When I replace %20 by %2B it seems to be working. But then there are two questions. First, how did it recognize spaces between, for example, 'University' and 'of', properly and it only had problems when I included 'the'. Second, this is a bit counter-intuitive to me. Usually, the search queries are formulated as search_term1+search_term2+search_term3. But here you are suggesting to formulate the query with spaces between search terms and '+' between multi-word search terms. Is that correct? Are you aware of any NYT article search query formulation guidelines?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not really sure how it works, but that is how they got the web site working. It seems your answer regarding Elasticsearch is a better solution. FWIW, in the future you can check the network tab and reverse engineer what the browser is doing.